# Word for something that is the last thing that shows that something existed

Tags: single-word-requests

What word do I use when I want to say that something is the last thing that shows that something existed?

Exact Scenario: There is a rod that extends from an electric pole, that was once there for trams.

Answer (score 2):

One word is **trace**. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trace) has

> NOUN
>   1A mark, object, or other indication of the existence or passing of something.

with an example

> *the aircraft disappeared without trace*

So one could say, perhaps,

> The last trace of Mr Miller was a pile of clothes on the beach.
>
> The last trace that remained of the crime was a bloodstain on the floor.

---

**Edit**: following detail added to the question.

> The last trace that a tramway once existed is a rod that extends from an electric pole.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be *vestige* defined as

> a small part of something that still exists after the rest of it has stopped existing

By the Oxford Learners dictionary

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vestige
Use as in 'last vestige'

Remnant is also a possibility, oxford dictionaries giving it the description

> a part or quantity that is left after the greater part has been used, removed, or destroyed

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remnant

Comment: This was my choice too. It seems to even contain in itself the idea of being at the end. One could smell a trace of the aroma of a person both after they have left and when they haven't arrived yet. A vestige seems to fit only at the end. So, the word *last* is not needed.

Comment: +1 for including *remnant*, which is what I thought of.